# import library from Github

Tags: python, github, volatility

I am new to Python and I am trying to import a library from Github, and the below one is the package i am trying to load on Jupyter:

https://github.com/jasonstrimpel/volatility-trading

I tried to do this yet with no luck.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='volatility-trading',
    version='0.0.1',
    url='https://github.com/jasonstrimpel/volatility-trading/',
    license='GPL-3.0-or-later',
    packages=['volatility','volatility/models'],
```

Would be awesome if anyone of you can give me a hand. Many thanks for helping.

Comment: what happens to the parenthesis you opened? It never closes.

Comment: Is the package installed on your device?

Comment: Thanks Sembei, I closed the parenthesis but also didn't work

Comment: Thanks Joe. Think I need to import the package from the url, but I haven't been able to do it so far.

Comment: Actually I tired to pip install import_from_github_com  and then re-run the code, still no luck out of it